# is this sentence gramatically correct? Do you think my sentences are too long?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, punctuation, sentence-choice

My first language is Spanish so I have a hard time with my vocabulary or writing grammatically correct. I have to respond to my professor's syllabus with something I liked about it. I think one of the sentences sounds off?
I also was wondering what do you think I should say instead of shy? I am not sure what feeling that is?

What I particularly liked about the syllabus was the description on your principles because you talked about feedback, I think I respond to feedback unwell at times too.

** I think I get discouraged when someone says I did something wrong because even if I find that I happen to make a mistake it is still hard for me to hear others criticize my work.**

I have never responded negatively though because I didn't want to accept any feedback, but more of feeling that I am not getting better. I do try to fix my mistakes as I get feedback. And I agree, I do learn when I realize mistakes.

Comment: Proofreading and writing advice are outside the scope of this forum. I will just mention that you need to say "I respond badly to feedback". _Unwell_ is an adjective meaning _ill_ or _sick_.

Comment: And it's **description of....** not **description on....** - although I think you mean **the explanation of** or **setting out of** rather than **description of**.